# Trigonometric inequality proof

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Can anyone help me in proving that $$\cos\theta > \frac{\left(x^a\cos\theta-(x-1\right)^a\cos\frac{\ln x\theta}{\ln(x-1)})\cos(\theta+\gamma)}{\cos\gamma},$$ where $a<1$, $x\in \mathbb{N}$, and $x\neq 1$?

Edit : I finally made some progress so that $ \cos\theta > x^a \cos2\theta - (x-1)^a\cos (\theta+\theta\frac{\ln(x-1)}{\ln x})$

Comment: What are $\gamma$ and $x$?

Comment: They are any variables and x>1

Comment: In that case this is not true: take $\theta=\pi/4$ and $\gamma=3\pi/4$ with $x=1.1$, $\alpha=2$. You get that RHS is bigger (checked on WA)

Comment: I said that x>1 not equal to 1

Comment: Yes, and $1.1>1$...

Comment: Can I say that x>=2 and includes only includes natural numbers , excluding 1 ?

Comment: That would reamin wrong. Try to experiment with the numbers. For $x=3,\alpha=2,\theta=\pi/4, \gamma=3\pi/4$ it is still wrong.

Comment: Please not that a<1 and also not equal to 1

Comment: Why do you think this holds? Have you seen it somewhere without proof? Or is it a conjecture of yours?

Comment: If not why? Can you provide any proof . I am almost sure.

Comment: You really need to include all of the conditions on the variables in your question! Is $a \in [0,1)$? What about $\theta$ and $\gamma$? Apparently $\gamma \not\equiv \frac{\pi}{2}\ (\operatorname{mod} \pi)$... what else? I edited your question to include what you've already said about $x$.